# The app references non-public selectors in :setRefreshInterval

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, flurry

When trying to upload an iOS app for the appstore I am getting an error stating that

```
The app references non-public selectors in :setRefreshInterval
```

I am using a lot of libraries in my project from different Ad Network SDKs to three20, upon investigation I found out that the static library FlurryAds.a contains these methods and may cause an app rejection.

[image: screen shot]

I have the latest Flurry SDK installed in fact I just downloaded it last night.

I asked one of my friends who recently integrated flurry ads that he got the same error but his app went through.

And now my question is did anyone else got this error while uploading the app to the appstore & if they did, were their app rejected?

For now I will be disabling FlurryAds but I will forward to your suggestions / pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is shown as a result of Flurry calling setRefreshInterval in two different mediated networks. Flurry is not calling any Apple private APIs. Many publishers have submitted with this, and since a private API is not called, there are no problems in submitting to the AppStore. (Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)